# Easily evaluate expression in Drake

Tags: drake

The motivation is this: I want to evaluate some expressions in Drake using my initial guess.

```
(Pdb) sum_torques[0][0]
<Expression "(0.22118181414246227 * F(0) + 0.025169594403141499 * F(1) + 0.24812114211450653 * F(3) + 0.11159816296412806 * F(6) - 0.58491827687679454 * F(10))">
(Pdb) self.F
array([[Variable('F(0)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(1)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(2)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(3)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(4)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(5)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(6)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(7)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(8)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(9)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(10)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(11)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(12)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(13)', Continuous)],
       [Variable('F(14)', Continuous)]], dtype=object)
```

How can I easily evaluate the first expression? I thought Evaluate would work, but it doesn't:

```
(Pdb) sum_torques[0][0].Evaluate(prog.GetInitialGuess(self.F))
*** TypeError: Evaluate(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: pydrake.symbolic.Expression, env: Dict[pydrake.symbolic.Variable, float] = {}, generator: pydrake.common._module_py.RandomGenerator = None) -> float
    2. (self: pydrake.symbolic.Expression, generator: pydrake.common._module_py.RandomGenerator) -> float

Invoked with: <Expression "(0.22118181414246227 * F(0) + 0.025169594403141499 * F(1) + 0.24812114211450653 * F(3) + 0.11159816296412806 * F(6) - 0.58491827687679454 * F(10))">, array([10.6457846 , 10.32468297, 10.51971119, 10.00005536, 10.31186022,
       10.42545154, 10.88533766, 10.67987946, 10.45612977, 10.48340862,
       10.78873943, 10.22944183, 10.8802976 , 10.31369239, 10.95745086])
```

I could of course rewrite the sum_torques expression using prog.InitialGuess for every expression I want to evaluate, but this is extremely cumbersome... I thought there would be some easy way to evaluate the expressions without doing that.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate a symbolic::Expression, you will need to provide a dictionary that maps each variable to its value. Here is the code

```py
env = {self.F[i][0] : prog.GetInitialGuess(self.F[i][0]) for i in range(self.F.shape[0])}
sum_torques[0][0].Evaluate(env)
```